# How to change single quotes to double quotes to final XML in Prolog with jaxb and XMLStreamWriter in Java

Tags: xml, spring, jaxb, marshalling

I have a perfectly working solution to marshal objects into final XML:

```
final String XSD_FILE_NAME = "my.xsd"

public void writeToFile(MyFile myFile) {
    try (OutputStream writer = new FileOutputStream(exactFilePath)) {
        Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller = new Jaxb2Marshaller();
        marshaller.setSchema(resourceLoader.getResource("classpath:file/my.xsd"));
        marshaller.setContextPath("com.my.project.type");
        marshaller.setMarshallerProperties(ImmutableMap.of(
                javax.xml.bind.Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, Boolean.TRUE,
                javax.xml.bind.Marshaller.JAXB_NO_NAMESPACE_SCHEMA_LOCATION, "my.xsd"
        ));
        marshaller.afterPropertiesSet();

        XMLStreamWriter streamWriter = XMLOutputFactory.newInstance().createXMLStreamWriter(writer, "UTF-8");
        StAXResult result = new StAXResult(streamWriter);
        marshaller.marshal(myFile, result);
        streamWriter.close();
    } catch (IOException | XMLStreamException e) {
        throw e;
    }
}
```

But I realized that the final XML file uses single quotes ONLY for Prolog (`<?xml ...>`). But for every other attribute in root and child elements, double quotes:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<myFile xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" attribute1="1" attribute2="2">
  <myChild/>
</myFile>
```

How can I set it to use double quotes also for XML Prolog?

Comment: I don't think JAXB can be configured for that nor that there is a sane way to circumvent it. Normally you shouldn't care about such a thing. Why are you even looking at this?

Comment: I just compared with an old file, where I had old solution, and there in the old file has  double quotes. I just wanted to have 100% the same as previously.

Comment: It always sucks to use automated serializers to universal formats and wanting them to produce the same lexical results rather than same semantic results. Better to not want that.

Answer (score 0):

If your factory is Woodstock.

```
XMLOutputFactory xif = XMLOutputFactory.newFactory();
 xif.setProperty("com.ctc.wstx.useDoubleQuotesInXmlDecl","true");
```